# How to clear req.session on clearing browser cookies in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, express-session

I am using `"express": "~4.14.0"` with `express-session` for saving username. Once  the user is logged in, I will save the user name in `req.session.authorizedUser = username` to display it in the application header.

When either the browser history is cleared or the browser is closed, I want to clear the session.

Please suggest me if there is any way to clear the session when doing any of these two operations. I have tried setting the `maxAge` option for session cookies, as shown below, but it doesn't reflects good:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "key test",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: !true, path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null}
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a browser doesn't notify a server when it deletes cookies (for whatever reason), there's no way of telling *purely on the server side* if a session should still be valid or not.

That's why most session stores have an expiry mechanism that will delete idle sessions after a specific amount of time (which is usually tied to `maxAge`).

For instance, the [`connect-mongo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) session store uses MongoDB's TTL feature to remove expired sessions from the database.

Apart from taking up a bit of storage space, idle sessions aren't a problem, though. When the user logs in again, a new session will be created for them, and the old one will eventually expire and be removed from storage.

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can maintain sessions in client side?

Comment: @DhyaS what exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to know on the client side when a session has expired, or something?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly. But JS sessionStorage is undefined in node JS

Comment: @DhyaS ultimately, it's the server that determines when a session expires. A client generally doesn't know if it has a valid session or not. The only way to make sure that there's a session active and valid is to query the server periodically.