# express-session, how to prevent session/cookie resource exhaustion attack?

Tags: node.js, cookies, web-applications, express-session, denial-of-service

**Setting**

I am currently trying to create a webapp using NodeJS Express, and I am using express-session for managing sessions and storing the sessions in redis.

For simplicity, I am going to have the client call the login service and I will just set the username of the authenticated user into the session.

Example:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  req.session.username = someUsername;
  res.send({authentication: "success"});
});
```

With this approach, a user can log in into the same account using different computers/browsers, etc. And they will be able to stay logged in until they log off or the session expires.

**Question**

Now, I was wondering what prevents a person from sabotaging by logging in, clearing cookies and logging in again (rinse and repeat)? Under this approach, the a user can create infinite amount of sessions and crash my application (out of memory or filling up my storage). How do other websites deal with this?

Comment: This might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782761/how-to-clear-req-session-on-clearing-browser-cookies-in-node-js

Comment: the question on that link seems to be a very similar use case to mine. and for the solution  I know idle sessions expire, but when the application gets attacked, there is no time for the session to expire

Comment: I think to make a good protection requires some active software. The first thing that comes to my mind is 
1) ddos protection - don't let anyone pour requests from an ip to the login route
2) you can write a piece of code that tracks the account that has some malicious activity and ban it.